# Why Is This Tail-Recursive Function So Much More Complicated?

Tags: recursion, racket, tail-recursion

So, I'm fiddling with some basic maths, and I wanted a function to convert between bases.

I wrote this function:

```
(define (convert-base from to n)
  (let f ([n n])
    (if (zero? n)
        n
        (+ (modulo n to) (* from (f (quotient n to)))))))
```

Which works for all my personal tests < base 10 and would as far as I can imagine function perfectly fine for tests > base 10 if I just added support for additional digits.

What's confusing me is that when I tried to make the function tail-recursive, I ended up with this mess (I've added some spacing for SO's benefit, because my code is not often clear or pretty):

```
;e.g. 10 2 10 should output 1010, 10 8 64 should output 100 etc.

(define (convert-base-tail from to n)
  (let f ([n n]
          [acc 0]
          [zeros 0])

    (begin (printf "n is ~a. acc is ~a. zeros are ~a.\n" n acc zeros)

    (cond [(zero? n) (let exp 
                       ([x acc]
                        [shft zeros])
                       (if (zero? shft)
                           x
                           (exp (* x 10) (- shft 1))))]
          [(zero? (modulo n to))
            (if (zero? acc)
                (f (quotient n to) (* acc from) (add1 zeros))
                (f (quotient n to) (* acc from) zeros))]
          [else (f (quotient n to) (+ (* acc from) (modulo n to)) zeros )]))))
```

My question is, essentially, why is the tail-recursive function so much more complicated? Is it inevitable, due to the nature of the problem, or is it due to an oversight on my part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It isn't, really:

```scm
(define (convert-base from to n)
  (let f ([n n] [mul 1] [res 0])
    (if (zero? n)
        res
        (f (quotient n to) (* mul from) (+ res (* mul (modulo n to)))))))
```

Testing

```scm
> (convert-base-y 10 2 10)
1010
> (convert-base-y 10 8 64)
100
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought there would be a better way of approaching it that I just missed, I was just completely blocking on it. Really frustrating. This makes so much more sense.